# How to take the start date of one field and end date of another to make a new field?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, so I have a table that looks like so with replicated id fields each with different start and end dates:

```
id              startDate              endDate
4052021011      2021-05-04 12:11:39    2021-05-04 12:16:54
4052021011      2021-05-04 12:20:50    2021-05-04 12:22:04
4052021011      2021-05-04 12:25:37    2021-05-04 12:32:08
```

And I want to perform a query that takes the earliest start date, the lastest end date from the same id and retuns the following:

```
id             startDate              endDate
4052021011     2021-05-04 12:11:39    2021-05-04 12:32:08
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Probably worth mentioning that I am using mySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like aggregation:

```
select id, min(startDate), max(endDate)
from t
group by id;
```

Do you have something actually more complex than this?  `GROUP BY` is very basic SQL functionality.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I think i was confusing myself making it too complex and its just not as complicated as I was thinking.